# Post and read postgresql data subsequently using javascript and php

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, leaflet

I'm trying to post data to a postgresql db, and to subsequently read from this db using PHP and display the data on a leaflet map.

I have a dropdown menu that when clicked sends data to a postgresql db :

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <select onchange="handlData()" value="false" name="val" id="val" class="selectors myDropdown">
    <option value="base">Choose value</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

These are my js functions :

```
function insert_function() {
    var formData = {
        val: $("#val").val(),
    };
    console.log(formData)
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "insert_query.php",
        data: formData,
        dataType: "json",
        encode: true,
    }).done(function (data) {
    }); 
};

function read_function(){
    $.ajax({url:'read_query.php',
        success: function(response){
        airbnbs = JSON.parse(response)
        console.log(airbnbs)
        lyr = L.geoJSON(airbnbs,{
        }).addTo(map)
    }
    })    
}

function handleData(){
    insert_function()
    read_function()
}
```

My problem is that my insert function is working correctly (it starts with an empty table every time, and gets filled every time an option is chosen). However, my read function return an empty array (even if my table is not empty).

However, for some reasons, it works when a I had a button to click to confirm the selection. For instance :

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <select onchange="insert_function()" value="false" name="val" id="val" class="selectors myDropdown">
    <option value="base">Choose value</option>
  </select>
</form>
<button type="button" onclick="read_function()">Click Me!</button>
```

My question is how could I skip the button part, and post, read, and display the data on the map directly when choosing an option.

Comment: One of the advantages of PDO, is that it can be used with different types of databases, including postgresql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget that AJAX calls are *asynchronous*. So there's a good chance your "read" function is executing and returning results before the "insert" function has finished, because you're actually running both AJAX requests in parallel. (The reason it works when you used a button would have been simply that you aren't running the two requests simultaneously, because it has to wait for the button click before doing the "read").

Instead, if you return the AJAX Promise from the "insert" function, you can use its "done" callback to make sure you don't run the "read" until the "insert" action has completed.

```
function insert_function() {
    var formData = {
        val: $("#val").val(),
    };
    console.log(formData)
    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "insert_query.php",
        data: formData,
        dataType: "json",
        encode: true,
    }); 
};

function read_function(){
    $.ajax({url:'read_query.php',
        success: function(response){
        airbnbs = JSON.parse(response)
        console.log(airbnbs)
        lyr = L.geoJSON(airbnbs,{
        }).addTo(map)
    }
    })    
}

function handleData(){
    var promise = insert_function()
    promise.done(function(data) {
      read_function()
    });
}
```